# Dedicated server that can run multiple Team Fortress 2 servers?

Tags: gaming, server, web-server

I rent several virtual private servers to run Team Fortress 2 servers. These servers all run SourceMod (an administration and plugin framework). Individual servers then run various SourceMod plugins to make the gaming experience unique.

I'd like to consolidate all of these into a server dedicated server, which I'd also use to run the MySQL database that our web page uses and a web server to host our forums. These forums receive a modest amount of traffic daily.

Requirements:

- Must be able to host 10-14 Team Fortress 2 server instances without causing lag to the players. Each server will host 24 players and approximately half of the servers will be near capacity 24 hours a day (based on current traffic)
- Must be able to handle MySQL database traffic
- Must be able to handle web traffic
- Price range: $100 - $125 a month
- Must be on a 100 Mbit line
- Most players are North American and European. I'd like a hosting location that serves both of these locations and keeps the lag low.

What type of server will be able to handle all of these requirements?

Comment: I created a [meta question](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/100/are-questions-related-to-hosting-requirements-on-topic) about third party host hardware

Comment: The location is irrelevant. If we're recommending a product, then it'll be located wherever you want/can locate it.

Comment: Maybe it's just me not getting the question, but, are you thinking of *buying* a server which you will host for this purpose, or *renting* one?

Comment: @JuanCarlosCoto, renting.

Comment: @Juan There isn't really any difference between buying and renting for our purposes. Either way, OP is looking to acquire hardware for himself.

Comment: What about hosting your own server at a colloc?